# When module Enabled in Content left & right panel so I want to hide javascript code in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I have add small javascript code in featured.tpl module OpenCart. So, when, featured module Enabled in Content top & bottom part. so, I want to show(run) it javascript code. but, when featured module Enabled in Content left & right panel. so, I want to **hide(not run)** it javascript code.

Please guide me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

**in .tpl file**

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_bottom' || $module['position'] == 'content_top') { ?>
//add your code Here
<?php } ?>
```

**add in .php file**

```
$this->data['module'] = $setting;
```