# Check module position in OpenCart 2.0

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I was using following code for Check module position. So, It is working fine in OpenCart 1.5.6.  [When module Enabled in Content left & right panel so I want to hide javascript code in OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675545/when-module-enabled-in-content-left-right-panel-so-i-want-to-hide-javascript-c)

but, it is not working in Opencart 2.0

How can be achieved in Opencart 2.0?

**in .tpl file**

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_bottom' || $module['position'] == 'content_top') { ?>
//add your code Here
<?php } ?>
```

**add in .php file**

```
$this->data['module'] = $setting;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in OC 2.0 this can be no longer achieved without a huge core code modification. Basically you would need to pass over a position for which the module is being instantiated to the module's constructor and then use this value in your module accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found simple solution. This is working like charm.

### Step 1

in .tpl file. (You want to that module. featured.tpl etc...)

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_bottom' || $module['position'] == 'content_top') { ?>
//add your code Here
<?php } ?>
```

### Step 2

add in .php file (You want to that module. featured.php etc...)

```
$data['module'] = $setting;
```

### Step 3 (if, You are used OpenCart 2.0.0.0 version)

catalog/controller/common/{**content_top, content_bottom, content_right, content_left**}.php,

Find the below code

```
if (isset($part[1]) && isset($setting[$part[1]])) {
```

and add the below code after

```
$setting[$part[1]]['position'] = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

### Step 3 (if, You are used OpenCart 2.0.1.x. version)

catalog/controller/common/{**content_top, content_bottom, content_right, content_left**}.php,

Find the below code

```
$setting_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($part[1]);
```

and add the below code after

```
$setting_info['position'] = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

OC 2.0 is a major update so lots of things working on OC 1.5.X might not work on OC 2.X

Eg OC 1.5.x we used to add layout to module now in OC 2.0 we add Modules to layout So In 1.5.x we used to find Module and it's associated positions, Now we find
Positions and it's associated Modules.

Suppose you are working on `\catalog\controller\common\content_top.php`

After

`$modules = $this->model_design_layout->getLayoutModules($layout_id, 'content_top');`

Which fetches all the modules set on `content_top` of the particular layout

Add

```
$search_text = 'featured'; // name of the module you want to find
$matched_top = array_filter($modules, function($el) use ($search_text) {
        return ( strpos($el['code'], $search_text) !== false );
});

if(!empty($matched_top)){
    $data['truevalue'] = 1;
}
```

Now in `content_top.tpl` you can write script

```
if(isset($truevalue)){
//here goes script code
}
```

Similarly You can do the same for `content_bottom` as well

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please read this question. Maybe, You can clearly understand. what I want to achieve. can you possible same thing(small code) achieved in Opencart 2.0? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675545/when-module-enabled-in-content-left-right-panel-so-i-want-to-hide-javascript-c